# Azure Web App (MVC) stripping off json body from result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, json.net, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and I want one of my controllers to return JsonResult. So, I created the following classes:

```
    public class TestResponse
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonBadRequestResult : JsonResult
    {
        public JsonBadRequestResult()
        {
        }

        public JsonBadRequestResult(string message)
        {
            this.Data = message;
        }

        public JsonBadRequestResult(object data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            this.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = 400;

            base.ExecuteResult(context);
        }
    }
```

And I have a simple controller method like this one:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestPost()
    {
        return new JsonBadRequestResult(new TestResponse { ErrorMessage = "Test Message" });

    }
```

When I call the TestPost method locally, I get the expected output.

```
{
    "ErrorMessage": "Test Message"
}
```

But, when I deploy this app as an Azure Web App and call the same TestPost method (using Postman), I get the following output. The Json body of the output is stripped off.

```
Bad Request
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try to add the this code to your web.config file,
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
</system.webServer>

Comment: Thanks! that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Swikruti Bose mentioned that we could add the following setting in the Web.config. It works correctly on my side. We could get more information about [httpErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpErrors/) Element from this [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497%28VS.90%29.aspx).

> PassThrough    Leaves the response untouched if an existing response exists

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
</system.webServer>
```